Ubuntu 24.04 Kernel Choice
I recently updated from 23.04 to 24.04.  The update completed normally but the system froze on the reboot.
I noticed that I have two kernels installed.
6.8.0-31 will not boot
6.5.0-35 boots and runs properly
I edited my grub file to load the 6.5 kernel through the advanced options tab but I suspect this is a short-term fix.
Would anyone happen to have any suggestions on a proper fix?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Sometimes your hardware simply does not work with a certain kernel. What you did is the correct fix. Maybe the next kernel update will work for you.
